# What makes a template?

Tags: word-request

I'm working on a software project that generates templates from raw data. We use "template" as a noun and a verb (though I don't know if using it as a verb is technically correct). Is there a good single word for a thing that makes templates? E.g. a templater or templatizer.

EDIT:

Just for fun, what are some silly names you can think of that I could use to annoy a coworker? He hates it when we say "templatizer," so let's see if he likes something like "Template-O-Matic" better :)

Comment: In computer world, maybe "wizard"?

Comment: Wizard is a general pattern of GUI that walks the user through step-by-step, definitely not what I'm looking for

Comment: @automaton interestingly, your username automaton is from the Greek *auto* (self) and *matos* (willing). "Auto" as a prefix and "matic" as a suffix are probably the most popular way to imply automation. Also I have added some more suggestions to annoy your colleague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not personally aware of a single word that describes one who, or that which creates templates, and while I'm not the ultimate authority I think it is fair to say that if you found an obscure word then it wouldn't be recognised by the average native English speaker.

One of your suggested words "*templater*" sounded very plausible but doesn't appear to be in any official dictionaries. The word *does* appear in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/templater), and although that doesn't count for much it means that at least somebody has used it before.

However if you are looking to *name* your software, the great thing about English is that you can use common rules to make up words as names and the meaning will be instantly recognised.

Names like...

- Templater
- Templatiser (or Templatizer in the US)
- Templatomatic
- AutoTemplate
- etc

...will be widely understood even though they are not (or may not be!) proper words. The fact that *Templater* has found its way into a wiki and gone unchallenged proves this point.

**Some additional names for your bonus 'name the software' question:**

- Mr. Template (for fans of *Back to the Future*)
- Supertemplate
- Templatebot
- Templat-inator (for fans of *Phineas and Ferb*)
- McTemplate
- Simon Templater
- Templater of Doom
- Templatey McTemplateface (every naming competition has to have this)

Comment: Thank you! This answer brings up something else (just for fun), question edited.

Comment: Simon Templater goes over my head, but I'm leaning toward Templat-inator considering that there is a Perry the Platypus plushie on my desk. Thanks!

Comment: @automaton I'm showing my age - Simon Templar is a fictional character from a 1960s British tv show called The Saint.